# [BlackBerry - Java]Error: Module 'My_Project' must be signed with the RIM Runtime Code Signing Key (RTT)

Tags: java, blackberry, code-signing

In the `BlackBerry Java` project, I try to add a feature to make sure the app can running on the backgroup.It runs normally on `BB`'s emulator but failed with an error while run in the device.

```
Error: Module 'My_Project' must be signed with the RIM Runtime Code Signing Key (RTT)
```

the problem occurs in code as below:

```
    private ApplicationIndicatorRegistry reg;
    private ApplicationIndicator indicator;
    public static  ApplicationIndicator AppIndi;
    public AfmobiMobile() {
        testMobile = this;

        reg=ApplicationIndicatorRegistry.getInstance();
        EncodedImage img=EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource("ic2.png");
        ApplicationIcon icon =new ApplicationIcon(img);
        indicator=reg.register(icon, false, true);
        AppIndi=reg.getApplicationIndicator();
}
```

All open handles to this volum would then be invaild.

Comment: Have you requested code signing keys from BlackBerry, and installed them in your development environment?

Comment: Yes I had request and got the code signin keys,import to the project

Comment: but have you signed your cod files? You need to sign your compiled cod files before installing them on an actual device.